# Access the velocity of a pan gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to get the velocity of a pan gesture, and I thought to use the sender's velocity property, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@IBAction func handleGesture(sender: AnyObject) {
    let v = sender.velocity
}
```

but it throws an error saying :

`"ambiguous use of 'velocity'"`

If that's not the way to access the velocity of a pan gesture, what is?

Answer (score 6):

UIPanGestureRecognizer does not have property named `velocity`. You should use `velocityInView` method.

```
func userPanned(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let v = sender.velocityInView(self.view)
}
```

Comment: well the `velocityInView` method returns a CGPoint, which I don't need, I need to take the velocity and compare it to a number

Comment: CGpoint has an X/Y CGFloat value which you can compare. There's velocity on both axis so you need to specify which one you want

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
@objc func customPanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.velocity(in: self.view)
}
```

[**Apple Developer Documentation** - velocity(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity)

Answer (score 0):

**For velocity, you need to do the following**

`sender.velocityInView(self.view)` gives you the pixels. In order to get the velocity, you need to divide it by 60 like this:

```swift
sender.velocityInView(self.view).x / 60 // For horizontal

sender.velocityInView(self.view).y / 60 // For vertical
```

**Hence, you can update the position just by adding it with your initial value like this:**

```swift
var initialLocation: CGPoint? // Global

initialLocation.x = (initialLocation ?? 0)

(initialLocation.x)! = (initialLocation.x)! + (sender.velocity(in: colorSlider!).x / 60) // For horizontal

(initialLocation.y)! = (initialLocation.y)! + (sender.velocity(in: colorSlider!).y / 60) // For vertical
```

Comment: why 60? 1px is 1 or 0.33 or 0.5 point depending the screen you use. Where 60 is come from?

Comment: @DmitrijRogov  you need to change the velocity to pixels per minute by dividing it by 60