# Change pangesture speed swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Is it possible to slow down pan gesture, to make it move with less speed.

Here's the code I'm using to move a 3d object

```
    @objc func handlePan(gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let numberOfTouches = gestureRecognize.numberOfTouches
    let translation = gestureRecognize.translation(in: gestureRecognize.view!)
    var widthRatio = Float(translation.x) / Float(gestureRecognize.view!.frame.size.width) - lastWidthRatio

    if (numberOfTouches == fingersNeededToPan) {
        //  WIDTH constraints
        if(widthRatio >= maxWidthRatioRight) {
            widthRatio = maxWidthRatioRight
        }
        if(widthRatio <= maxWidthRatioLeft) {
            widthRatio = maxWidthRatioLeft
        }

        self.artRoomScene.boxnode.eulerAngles.y = Float(2 * Double.pi) * widthRatio
        //for final check on fingers number
        lastFingersNumber = fingersNeededToPan
    }

    lastFingersNumber = (numberOfTouches>0 ? numberOfTouches : lastFingersNumber)

    if (gestureRecognize.state == .ended && lastFingersNumber==fingersNeededToPan) {
        lastWidthRatio = widthRatio
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the desired value a function of the [`velocity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity) property of your `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 0):

[Access the velocity of a pan gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748219/access-the-velocity-of-a-pan-gesture)

"sender.velocityInView(self.view) gives you the velocity in pixels per second. In order to get the exact velocity, you need to change the velocity to pixels per minute by dividing it by 60 like this:

sender.velocityInView(self.view).x / 60 - For horizontal

sender.velocityInView(self.view).y / 60 - For vertical

Hence, you can update the position just by adding it with your initial value like this:

var initialLocation: CGPoint? -> Global

initialLocation.x = (initialLocation ?? 0)

(initialLocation.x)! = (initialLocation.x)! + (sender.velocity(in: colorSlider!).x / 60) - For horizontal

(initialLocation.y)! = (initialLocation.y)! + (sender.velocity(in: colorSlider!).y / 60) - For vertical

Thanks."